# I use JabRef for ordering my refs but how to get Comma insted of dot

Tags: jabref

Following is produced by jabRef :

```
@Article{Lewis1992a,
  Title                    = {An injector/amplifier double target configuration for the Ne-like Ge X-ray laser scheme},
  Author                   = {C. L. S. Lewis and D. Neely and D.M. O'Neill and J.O. Uhomoibhi and M.H. Key and Y. Al Hadithi and G.J. Tallents and S.A. Ramsden},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Comm.},
  Year                     = {1992},
  Pages                    = {71-76},
  Volume                   = {91},

  Owner                    = {le},
  Timestamp                = {2015.01.12}
}
```

but when I compile it I have following :

> C. L. S. Lewis, D. Neely, D.M. O’Neill, J.O. Uhomoibhi, M.H. Key, Y.
>   Al Hadithi, G.J. Tallents, and S.A. Ramsden. An injector/amplifier
>   double target configuration for the ne-like ge x-ray laser scheme.
>   Opt. Comm., 91:71–76, 1992.

How to make manage that dots before and after title convert to comma (. An injector/amplifier double target configuration
for the ne-like ge x-ray laser scheme.)?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) Jabref is a citation manager, its only job is to make it easy to manage the data in a `.bib` file. It has nothing at all to do with how the data is formatted by `bibtex`. Might be a good idea to tell us more about your document, for example which `bibtex` style you are using.

Comment: \bibliographystyle{plain}

Comment: You will have to find a more appropriate bibtex style.

Comment: You should use `biblatex`, as it is easier to customise.

Comment: I changed it to \bibliographystyle{unsrt} , but it is still same as using \bibliographystyle{plain}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `biblatex`. The default is not very different from `plain` style, and it is relatively easy to customise, as it uses a latex syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{title.bib}
@Article{Lewis1992a,
Title = {An injector/amplifier double target configuration for the Ne-like Ge X-ray laser scheme},
Author = {C. L. S. Lewis and D. Neely and D.M. O'Neill and J.O. Uhomoibhi and M.H. Key and Y. Al Hadithi and G.J. Tallents and S.A. Ramsden},
Journal = {Opt. Comm.},
Year = {1992},
Pages = {71-76},
Volume = {91},

Owner = {le},
Timestamp = {2015.01.12}
}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{title.bib}

\renewcommand\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

test \cite{Lewis1992a}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]